# cv2 imdecode returns none with base64 string

Tags: linux, python-3.x, base64, opencv, python

When i try to convert base64 string into image i am getting none in CV2. 
Following is my code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def bsae62toimage(imgvalue):
    imge = "R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7"

    nparr = np.fromstring(imge,np.uint8)
    print(nparr.shape)
    img1 = cv2.imdecode(nparr,cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    print(img1.shape)
```

It is printing the numpy array but `cv2.imdecode` is returning `None`. Can you help me to find the problem in my code?

**My Findings:** np.fromstring it returns 1D array. I assume it should it should return 3D array. But i may be wrong.

Comment: dear downvoters - leave your valuable comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is unclear as from where have you obtained the `imge = "R0lGODlhEA..."` variable. I would present an ideal flow for converting OpenCV image to base64 string and converting it back to OpenCV img as:

```
import cv2
import base64
import numpy as np


def to_base64(img):
    _, buf = cv2.imencode(".png", img)

    return base64.b64encode(buf)


def from_base64(buf):
    buf_decode = base64.b64decode(buf)

    buf_arr = np.fromstring(buf_decode, dtype=np.uint8)

    return cv2.imdecode(buf_arr, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)


img = cv2.imread("/path/to/img.png")
img_base64 = to_base64(img)
img_decoded = from_base64(img_base64)

print img_decoded.shape
```

Also the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html#imdecode) states that:

> If the buffer is too short or contains invalid data, the empty
>   matrix/image is returned.

It seems to me that `imge = "R0lGODlhEA..."` is invalid.

Comment: I am getting this string from JAVA. I am trying to integrate the model written in Tensorflow into the JAVA application. The JAVA application emits the image into base64 string

Comment: I think you should read the Java method documentation carefully and compare the results of Python and Java on same image, to see if base64 encoded data is consistent on both sides for a smaller image say 10x10. Also share the Java code for base64 conversion if possible

Comment: So, What i am doing is - I render a webpage using selenium and take the screenshot using following code - String imagecontent = null;
    if(screenshotenabled){
    imagecontent = driver.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BASE64);
    }

Comment: Also in the code you have given i made a small change - def to_base64(filepath):

    with open(filepath, "rb") as imageFile:
        bstr = base64.b64encode(imageFile.read())
        
        return bstr
when i run the script with this change it is giving me wrong size :  (2184, 1280, 4).